# #if #else #endif directives

Tags: c#, wpf

```
#if DEBUG               
         e.Handled = false; 
#else
        ShowUnhandledException(e);
#endif
```

When trying to use the above directives the line after "if" appears as code and executes but the line after else remains grey and does not execute. The endif statement works. How to get the else directive to work as a line of code?

DEBUG define constant is ticked in setup!

Comment: `#if` directives determine is the code is compiled at all. When you're in debug mode, the code in the `#else` block is completely ignored. It's really not clear what you're asking here.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean how to get the code under `else` to execute *instead* of the code under `if`, then simply untick DEBUG in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

May i suggest something like this:

```
bool isDebugging;
#if DEBUG
    isDebugging = true;
#else
    isDebugging = false;
#endif

if(isDebugging)
{
    e.Handled = false;
}
else
{
    ShowUnhandledException(e);
}
```

I often have some kind of static variable with an enum representation of the buildmode to modify specific behaviours when debugging (such as not sending mails etc)